# Ng-Repeat, how to test for last ng-show element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I am not trying to add a different class for the last element of an ng-repeat.

I have data to display:

```
$scope.sizes = [{name:XS,available:true},{name:S,available:true},{name:M,available:false},{name:L,available:true},{name:XL,available:false}];
```

I want to display the range of data that contains true, i.e. display the above as "XS → L" (note missing out the M option).

Best I have come up with is using ng-repeat:

```
<span ng-repeat="size in sizes track by $index"
                      ng-init="sizeIndex = $index"
                      ng-show="size.available == true && (sizeIndex == 0  || sizeIndex == (sizes.length -1))">
                    {{size.short}}<span ng-show="sizeIndex ==0"> → </span>
                </span>
```

As expected this fails because size XL available == false, and it won't work if size XS is unavailable.

Is there a permutation of the display logic that I haven't thought of? Or is there a 'proper' way to test if an element is the last (or first) *shown* in a list?

Comment: will `$last`  help you with a `filter` don't filter you rows with ng-show etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `filter` by `available` then a simple `$first` n `$last` will work

```
  <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="size in sizes | filter: {available:true}">
   <div ng-show="$first">{{size.name}}</div>
    <div ng-show="$last">{{size.name}}</div>
  </li>
```

demo https://plnkr.co/edit/QHIKrUOudSYpczWuVdCe?p=preview this a fork of the angular doc example

Comment: Thanks for this answer, really simple.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to calculate the result in your controller before trying to display it:

```
$scope.sizes = [
    {name: "XS", available: true},
    {name: "S", available: true},
    {name: "M", available: false},
    {name: "L", available: true},
    {name: "XL", available: false}
];

DisplayRange();

function DisplayRange () {
    var BeginSize = null, EndSize = null;
    for (var i=0; i < $scope.sizes.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.sizes[i].available === true && BeginSize == null) {
            BeginSize = $scope.sizes[i].name;
        }
        if ($scope.sizes[i].available === true) {
            EndSize = $scope.sizes[i].name;
        }
    }
    $scope.FormattedSizes = BeginSize + " → " + EndSize;
}
```

What this is doing is scanning through each item in the `$scope.sizes` array.  When it finds the first available item, it assigns that name to `BeginSize`.  And each time it sees an available item, it will assign that name to `EndSize`.  We can be sloppy with `EndSize` because eventually the loop will reach the last available item and assign it to `EndSize` which will make it correct.

In your HTML, reference it like this:

```
<span>{{ FormattedSizes }}</span>
```

Comment: Thank you very. I like your answer as it gives a very versatile and awesomely described method. I put the $first||$last answer as the 'Answered' because it is simpler and good for my application.  Thanks for your help though :)